# Stringing on first layer unless I squish it

Tags: print-quality

I switched over to a new filament recently (Sunlu PLA) and I can't get the first layer details to stick properly without squishing the first layer way too much. Prints don't always fail, but little circles and the initial skirt rarely stick as they should. The issue appears to be that when it starts to extrude at a new location, it's not always close enough or extruding fast enough for the initial filament to stick and it gets lifted on the next pass. Other things stick just fine, it's just at these transitions where things lift a little. My bed is level and in general things are printing just fine. It's just the start/end of initial layers that tend to have problems and lift just enough to cause problems later.

If I lower my nozzle enough, I can get it to stick more reliably but then I have other problems because the first layer is so squished that the ridges rise and cause problems later.

I've read dozens of articles and tried all these things already:

- Dried my filament
- Adjusted my Z-offset (BLTouch)
- Attempted to recalibrate my retraction settings
- Replaced my nozzle, cleaned the hotend, and replaced the Bowden tube.
- Tried different temperature settings
- Cleaned the bed
- Calibrated my E-steps and played around with flow rates further

It used to print fine, so I guess it could just be the filament but I'm hoping there's something I can still do. I'm using an Ender 3 v2 with a BLTouch, new springs, replaced Bowden tube and red metal extruder. Printing at 210 °C with 60 °C bed.

[image: Beginning of print on printer bed with stringing errors]

[image: Beginning of print on printer bed with detached skirt]

Comment: What type of print bed do you have? Glass, BuildTak, PEI? Printer model might also be helpful. Please update the question by [edit].

Comment: Would you mind editing your post to include some kind of picture aswell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using 75 °C for the bed and 220 °C or highest recommended extrusion temperature for Sunlu PLA for the first layer, then lower the temperatures to 210 °C with 60 or 65 °C bed for subsequent layers.

Other options are Elmer's glue stick, a glue stick specified for a 3D printer bed, or hair spray.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll give this a try. So far I've been working around the issue by lowering the nozzle and then raising it once the outlines are complete.

Comment: green tape is great too! :)